# What will be the $n^{th}$ term of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Original question is to check whether the given series is convergent or divergent.

$$1+\frac{1^2\times 2^2}{1\times 3\times5}+\frac{1^2\times2^2\times3^2}{1\times3\times5\times7\times9}+\cdots$$

But to get to that question, I need to find the $n^{th}$ term of this series. I have figured out that numerator is $(n!)^2$ but can't figure out the denominator. Please help

Comment: $(4n-3)!!$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial (not that this notation/name is needed if you see what the pattern is, but perhaps the reference is useful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{1 \times 3 \times \ldots \times 9}=\frac{2 \times 4 \times \ldots \times 10}{10!}=\frac{(5!)(2^5)}{10!}=\frac{(2\times 3 -1)!(2^5)}{(2(2\times 3-1))!}$$

In general $$a_n = \frac{(2n-1)!2^{2n-1}(n!)^2}{(2(2n-1))!}$$

Comment: Shouldn't that numerator be $(5!)(2^5)$? A single power of $2$ isn't enough to double all those factors.

Comment: Yikes, you are right. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My first step
in this type of problem
is to get rid of the "..."
and write it in terms of
$\sum$ and $\prod$.

For
$1+\frac{1^2\times 2^2}{1\times 3\times5}+\frac{1^2\times2^2\times3^2}{1\times3\times5\times7\times9}+\cdots
$
the $n$-th term is
$a_n
=\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n i^2}{\prod_{j=1}^{2n-1} (2i-1)}
$.

At this point,
there are a few ways
to see what happens.
I'll start with
the ratio of consecutive terms.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
&=\dfrac{\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2}{\prod_{j=1}^{2n+1} (2i-1)}}{\dfrac{\prod_{i=1}^n i^2}{\prod_{j=1}^{2n-1} (2i-1)}}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\prod_{j={2n}}^{2n+1} (2i-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{(4n-1)(4n+1)}\\
&\to \dfrac1{16}
\qquad\text{for large } n
\quad\text{this, as pointed out by  Claude Leibovici, is 1/16, not 1/4}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
the sum converges.

Comment: May be $\to \frac 1 {16}$ instead. Cheers.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. So it converges even faster. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!^2}{(4n-3)!!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n!^2 2^{2n-1} (2n-1)!}{(4n-2)!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{4^n(4n-1)}{\binom{2n}{n}\binom{4n}{2n}}$$
can be written as
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}(4n-1)\frac{8n^2}{4^{2n}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin\theta)^{2n-1}\,d\theta\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin\phi)^{4n-1}\,d\phi$$
or as
$$ 128\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin\theta\sin^3\phi\left(48+\sin^2\theta\sin^4\phi\right) \left(16+5\sin^2\theta\sin^4\phi\right)}{(16-\sin^2\theta\sin^4\phi)^4}\,d\theta\,d\phi$$
which clearly is the integral over a square of a non-negative, continuous and bounded function.
It follows that the original series is convergent. It does not look unlikely that by the tangent half-angle substitution the original series, which equals
$$\phantom{}_3 F_2\left(1,2,2;\tfrac{3}{4},\tfrac{5}{4};\tfrac{1}{16}\right)$$
has a nice closed form, but I am honestly too lazy to check if it really is the case. Anyway, the radius of convergence of any $\phantom{}_{p+1}F_p$ equals one, hence the convergence of the original series also follows from the last representation by just noticing that $\frac{1}{16}<1$.